# fitting both buttons inside the form

Tags: jquery, css

I have two buttons as seen here on the right.
[image]

"Add Global Payer Contract" and the down arrow. I want the down arrow to be to the right of the Add Global Payer Contract, but I cannot seem to get it there.

Here is the code for it:

```
.bar
    %h1.pull-left= t('payer_contracts.payer_contracts')
    .btn-group.pull-right.dropdown-end
      = button_to t('payer_contracts.new_global_payer_contract'), new_payer_contract_path, class: 'btn pull-left', method: :get, params: { contract_type: 'global_contract_sub_type' }
      %button.btn.icon-decrement{"aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-haspopup" => "true", "data-toggle" => "dropdown", :type => "button"}
      %ul{"aria-hidden" => "true", :role => "menu"}
        %li
          = link_to t('payer_contracts.new_bpci_payer_contract'), new_payer_contract_path, params: {contract_type: 'bpci_contract_sub_type'}
```

For some reason the down arrow goes below it and not to the right of it.

When I inspect it, I see this:

[image]

I thought the .pull-right, would make everything to the right. Any ideas?

Comment: Well I don't understand your code, but you can try wrapping both in a div and set the div style to `display: inline-block`